# Implementing NSApplication delegate protocol for openFile in PyObjC

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, appdelegate, pyobjc

I want to do this in Python (pyobjc)

```
-(BOOL) application: (NSApplication*)sharedApplication openFile:(NSString*) fileName {
...
}
```

My delegate is a Python class like this:

```
class ApplicationDelegate(NSObject):
    ...
    def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, notification):
    ...
    def applicationWillTerminate_(self, sender):
    ...
```

How can I implement NSApplication delegate protocol for openFile in PyObjC?

Comment: Just implement the method. What's the problem you have?

Comment: I cannot translate the Objective-C syntax to Python correctly. I'm not familiar with Objective-C convention. Any help would be appreciated. Particularly the correct syntax for method signature in PyObjC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Objective-C method name is "application:openFile:", colons included. [PyObjC translates ObjC names by replacing colons with underscores](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/core/intro.html#underscores-and-lots-of-them). So the method name you need is "application_openFile_":

```
class ApplicationDelegate (NSObject):
    def application_openFile_(self, application, fileName):
        pass
```

Since `NSApplicationDelegate` is an "informal protocol" and the methods are optional [there's no need in Python to declare your conformance](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/core/protocols.html#informal-protocols-and-pyobjc). If there were, the protocol would be represented on the Python side by a mixin-style class, and your class definition would look like this:

```
class AppDelegate (NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate):
    pass
```

Comment: Added 'self' as first argument of the def clause. Works great! Thank you very much :D

Comment: Oh, yup, sorry about that: compiled this by brain and I haven't done PyObjC in quite some time. Glad I could help.